# Nowadays, what is the best Image Processor library for PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

On my company we're using the native lib (GD) and I would like to know what would be, nowadays, the best option in terms efficiency for image manipulations like resize or crop, since we're not very happy with what we have now.

We've been reading and seriously considering ImageMagick. Any thoughts on it and on other good alternatives would be appreciated as well?

Comment: For raster image manipulation I believe ImageMagick is the best but [Cairo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.cairo.php) looks to show some promise although documentation is nowhere near complete.

Answer (score 0):

What data have you obtained so far?

What functionality are you looking for? I would suggest a Google search first if you have done no research

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=image+Magick+vs+gd&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

**AND**

ImageMagick is not a PHP image processing library, it's a stand-alone package that can be accessed from PHP. It is incredibly more feature-rich than GD. See the ImageMagick Usage page with hundreds of examples. GD supports very primitive operations only (copying, resizing, geometric primitives, basic text rendering).

Everyday things ImageMagick does better:

1. Can handle more image formats (more than 100 IIRC - GD supports only
   5)
2. Better rendering of True-Type fonts, takes into consideration
       kerning hints in the font
3. Doesn't use the PHP script's memory

Comment: I've searched but I couldn't find any recent thread/discussion/article  on this matter and my main point would be if there is any alternative good to GD and ImageMagick that is best in terms of cropping and resizing images, Otherwise we are seriously considering to change to ImageMagick.

Comment: What I eventually decided to do, because, we are just supporting recent browsers versions, was to use the HTML5 Canvas to do all the transformations on the Client Side.

And because we use Amazon s3 to store all files uploaded, we are uploading directly the images from the browser to Amazon servers via CORS request, instead of using our server as a proxy, which makes all the process much faster.